# Sharepoint foundation 2013 FBA (Claim based authentication issue)

Tags: forms-authentication

I'm trying to configure FBA on sharepoint 2013 foundation. Followed each steps described in technet. Still getting error "

> An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The server
>   was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more
>   information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs..

"

May be in past i have seen some comments regarding this from your side but now not able to get it. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, there could be many reasons. Please check the following possible suggestions:

1. ​The most likely cause is that you are using forms-based authentication (FBA), which in SharePoint 2010 means you are necessarily using Claims, and you have misconfigured one of the several web.config files you need to set up for FBA. Check them carefully for typos.
2. Claims to Windows Token Service (C2WTS) is not running. Check the Services on Server page to make sure that it is Started.

For more information, see:

[Configuring SharePoint 2013 Forms-Based Authentication with SQLMemberShipProvider](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider.aspx)

[Configuring Forms Based Authentication in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/)

Comment: I have checked every web.config files / C2WTS. Same code is working on Sharepoint Enterprise 2013 edition.